# Tata photon max Wi-Fi Data card is not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please Help!

Tags: usb-modem, wifi-hardware-switch

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have Tata photon max wifi data card. It was working when i installed it. It was randomly working after that. But, after installing updates it is not working at all. Please provide some solution.

Comment: It stopped working after installing ubuntu updates, or any update provided by Tata-photon ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Tata Photon card myself. It was installed in 13.10 and is still working when i upgraded to 14.04. 
Try starting the Photon connection manager from terminal and paste the output here.

That would help in tracking the problem.